# Kernel crashes when running cnn in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

'I am a window10 user I'm running tensorflow in jupyter notebook, perceptron works fine, but cnn kernel crashes. I also tried increasing the buffer size, but the kernel keeps crashing.
I made a model with cnn in Kolab, and when I download the model and run it with a Jupyter notebook, the kernel dies. Also, making a model with a jupyter notebook kills the kernel. In jupyter notebook, training with perceptron is possible, but with cnn it always kills the kernel.
But .summary() works. What's wrong?'
'''

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


testcnn=tf.keras.models.load_model("my_lasthomework_cnn.h5")
testcnn.summary()
import pandas as pd

from PIL import Image
test_dir='dir'
test_csv = pd.read_csv(test_dir+'test.csv')
test_images=[]
for file in test_csv['data']:
    image=np.array(Image.open(test_dir+'test/'+file))
    test_images.append(image)
test_images=np.array(test_images)


for i in test_images:
    p1=testcnn.predict(i.reshape(1,64,64,3))
    print(np.argmax(p1))
```

'''

Comment: All the crashes are in the same notebook ?

Comment: Yes the other pc is using the cpu and this pc is using the gpu. The other pc works fine, but the pc using the gpu doesn't.

Comment: I had this problem before, and it was due to a corrupted notebook. I pasted the code to a brand new notebook and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the coursera program on machine / deep learning and came through to same problem - my hp laptop with GPU would crash when running model training notebook.

Running on WSL with cuda on Windows 11 Preview, and spent some time looking to find the root cause / solution to the problem.

However, suggestion above about corrupted notebook and moving code to a new note (and a separate / new virtual environment) solved the problem right away.

I have to say though, I dont know the root cause of the failure, just that the new notebook / venv solved the problem.